# Threading a function in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent

I have a for-loop that will run a fixed number of times, usually in the 100-300 range depending on the input.  Every iteration of this loop calls a function that I want to be threaded.  The function to thread grabs data from an input file, does some stuff with it, then writes it out in a new format to an output file...

Here is some high-level code:

```
void myClass::processFile()
{
    ...

    for (int index = 0; index < 200; index++)
    {
        //Function or loop to thread
        generateData(someMapOfMaps1[index], someMapOfMaps2[index]);
    }
}
```

Then inside generateData within the ***same*** class:

```
void myClass::generateData(QMap<float, foo*> mapA, QMap<float, foo*> mapB)
{
    //read in data from a file
    //process data
    //write data to a different file
}
```

I played around with `QtConcurrent::run()` and `QtConcurrent::mapped()` but didn't have much luck.  I believe `mapped()` would have been a great choice, but my function takes 2 maps instead of just one.

I was using this as a resource, around slide 25: http://www.develer.com/promo/workshop/enhancing_with_multi_threading.pdf

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- read this http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwaitcondition.html
- inherit your class from `QThread`
- put in `run()` call of your function in endless loop
- stop loop by `QWaitCondition` before call generateData
- wake up condition in your `for` cycle

Answer (score 0):

Put the loop, files read/write, 'some stuff', the lot in the thread.  Trying to thread off one function call per loop is, well, just too much avoidable inter-thread comms.  Pack the filespecs etc. into a myClass object, signal it to the thread and just let it go...